WPF application exceeds monitor width in fullscreen while using SingleBorderWindow and WindowChrome
I want to create a WPF application with a custom toolbar/control buttons. Most sources instruct you to use WindowStyle.None and use a WindowChrome. This does remove the default Windows toolbar and it allows me to resize the application and double click to switch from WindowState.Normal to WindowState.Maximized and back.
The only things this setup misses, are the default Windows animations when switching WindowState and minimizing the application. After some researching I found out that the WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow (and WindowStyle.ThreeDBorderWindow) does include these animations.
The only issue now is that the application overflows the screen by a pixel or so on the right when the WindowState is Maximized on a multiple monitor setup.
I have tried to switch the WindowStyle to None when the WindowState switches to Maximized, but this does not seem to work and the application still overflows into my right monitor.
This is the XAML:
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
        StateChanged="MainWindow_OnStateChanged">

</Window>

And this is the C#:
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowChrome chrome = new();
        WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, chrome);
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
        }
    }

So basically I have to choose between a properly sized application without animations, or an application with animations that does not fit on the screen nicely.

Remove the Height and Width specification from the Window. One rarely specifies an absolute size for the Window ... you see that creep when the "origin" is no longer (0,0). The Window should "resize" itself based on it's content, when not maximized. You design for the smallest screen you intend to support, then "work up" for a "fluent" / fluid UI. Mobile through to XBox, and beyond. Use Vertical and Horizontal Alignment to "center" or "stretch", left, right.

I have this problem before. Try to wrap your Grid(or whatever main control you're using) info Border the following way:
<Border>

    <!--  Setting border style triggers to prevent the edges Window out of the screen  -->
    <Border.Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">

            <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                             Value="Maximized">

                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="6" />

                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                             Value="Normal">

                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="0" />

                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

    </Border.Style>

    <!-- Your main control -->
    <Grid>
    
    </Grid>

</Border>

And also it works for me with the following WIndowsChrome:
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="1"
                  CornerRadius="0"
                  GlassFrameThickness="1"
                  ResizeBorderThickness="4" />

</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

Also I found the solution here.
Please let me know if it works for you or not
